# Adding default values firebase

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am using Firebase-UI in my android project with email/password provider. The structure of the database is:

```
profiles
    user-id
         age
         height
    user-id
```

On signup I want to enter a new node in profiles with default values. The user can edit and save  the values later. For an existing user I just want to read the values and display them in the UI. I have tried using ChildEventListener and dataSnapshot.hasChild(uid) to detect if the user already exists but it isn't working. This is the AuthStateListener:

```
mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if(user != null)
            {
                onSignedInInitialize(user);
            }
            else
            {
                onSignedOutCleanup();
                startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().setProviders(providers).build(), SIGN_IN);
            }
        }
    };
```

This is what I have tried:

```
private void onSignedInInitialize(final FirebaseUser user) {
    userRef = mProfilesDBReference.child(user.getUid());

    if(mValueEventListener == null)
    {
        mValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null)
                {
                    UserProfile profile = new UserProfile("username", null, 100, 100);
                    userRef.setValue(profile);
                    UpdateUI(profile);
                }
                else
                {
                    UserProfile profile = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserProfile.class);
                    UpdateUI(profile);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
    }

    userRef.addValueEventListener(mValueEventListener);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the userid is stored in `uid`;
You can fetch the height and age like this.

```
DatabasReference userRef = database.getReference("profiles").child(uid);
userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   if(dataSnapshot.getValue() == null){
      //User data doesnt exist
   }
  else
   {
    HashMap<String,String> userMap = 
      (HashMap<String,String>)dataSnapshot.getValue();
     String age = userMap.get("age");
    String height = userMap.get("height");
   }
}

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
 });
```

Note that  i have assumed that you have stored them as Strings , firebase usually converts ints to longs. So if you used ints , convert the value type of hashmap as `Long`.
A much better way would be to create a POJO class.